# When will invokedynamic be available in the standard JDK?

Tags: java, dynamic-languages, invokedynamic

I'm eager to start working with dynamic languages on top of Java.

How long before this is part of the standard JDK?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you using dynamic languages on the JVM today. There's plenty available. "Invoke dynamic" will just improve the performance with a bit of extra juice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Java 7 is released. Currently, best guess is late 2010, but subject to change.

[Keep an eye out](http://java7.tumblr.com/). Last mention of JSR-292 was [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/twisti/entry/jsr_292_server_compiler_support), about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: Also John Rose's blog, http://blogs.sun.com/jrose/, has a _lot_ of information in JSR-292.

Answer (score 0):

Java language does not support dynamic language. However, you can use invokedynamic instruction in your java program with some library, like asm.